# Downloading a mp3 with requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, python-requests

im having a trouble understanding the module requests, i understand that http have post,get, put, delete methods, but i think i need to know more about how requests works, i have read the documentation but still i have a lot of questions about how to do something, this is the first time i try to make a script for web without selenium or mechanize

im trying to interact with [vubey.yt](https://vubey.yt/), but i cant make my vubey url change at what i want(or what i see when i manually use the pag) i can send my data, and it changes the url, but if i copy that url and navigate manually, it does nothing... so i dont understand whats happening, because i dont have any visual clue

here is my code (python 3.5):

```
def Descarga(youtubeid):
       # also i have tried only sending videoURL without quality and sub, but is the same
        r = requests.get('https://vubey.yt/', params={'videoURL': youtubeid, 'quality': '320', 'submit': 'Convert+To+MP3'})

        print(r.url, r.status_code)

Descarga("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
```

if someone could link me a tutorial for really understand how to use this module or tell me what im doing wrong or misunderstanding about this module i ll thank so much

Comment: You should analyze the traffic going on between the browser and vubey.yt, and you'll see it's not just a GET. There's a POST to begin with, which then returns you somehow to a different URL (some like https://vubey.yt/?download=<uuid>), which is the page that will show you the "converting..." message, and finally show you the "click here to download" button. Use the web-browser console to see what's really going on, and then you can surely find your implementation.

Comment: Sometimes sites have a backend API for scripts. I searched "vubey api" and got several hits. Nothing jumped out immediately as a backend api but I got [this](https://teqch.com/vubey-video-to-mp3-converter-now-supports-soundcloud/) from the implementor and there may be more info if you dig.

Comment: Yep, when I use requests I always figure out what the browser is doing, usually by hitting F12 (At least in Chrome /FFox), then going to the Network tab. In there you simply monitor the requests made by your browser and try to replicate them in requests.

Answer (score 0):

See with me the site code:

```
<form class="w-clearfix" name="wf-form-signup-form" data-name="conversionForm" form action="/" method="post" id="conversionForm">
```

It's a form. The form is using the method 'post' in the same page.

```
<input class="w-input field" id="videoURL" type="text" placeholder="Video URL" name="videoURL" data-name="videoURL" required="required">
```

The first data "videoURL".

```
<select class="w-select" id="quality" name="quality" data-name="quality" required="required">
```

The second data "quality".

```
<input class="w-button button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert To MP3">
</form>
```

The submit button is not important. Ignore it.

Now, lets pythonify.

```
import requests

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c'
quality = '320'

post_data={ 'videoURL': video_url, 'quality': quality }

response = requests.post('https://vubey.yt/', data=post_data)

print(response.url, response.status_code)
```

Now you can parse the response.content and search for "Please wait" until the conversion is completed.